# Capture xml from an api call and write to database table using sqlxmlbulkload

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, xml, streamwriter

I'm wanting to capture xml returned from an api call and write this directly to an SQLserver table using SQLXMLBulkLoad. So far, I'm able to caprture the xml and write it to a file, I then use SQLXMLBulkLoad to read the file and load it into a table in SQLServer. This works but saving to a file first is clearly inefficient. The documentation states that SQLXMLBulkLoad can accept input from an ADO stream object but I can't figure out how to get this working. Can anyone help? Apologies is the answer is too obvious! The code I'm using so far is:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO

Partial Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page



Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim strURL As String = "http://myapicall...."

    Dim strRequest As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(strURL)
    Dim strResponse As HttpWebResponse = strRequest.GetResponse()
    strRequest.KeepAlive = True
    Dim objStreamReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(strResponse.GetResponseStream())
    Dim strSourceCode As String = objStreamReader.ReadToEnd()

    Dim objStreamWriter As StreamWriter

    'Pass the file path and the file name to the StreamWriter constructor.
    objStreamWriter = New StreamWriter("myfile.xml")

    'Write a line of text.
    objStreamWriter.WriteLine(strSourceCode)

    'Close the file.
    objStreamWriter.Close()


    Dim objBL = CreateObject("SQLXMLBulkLoad.SQLXMLBulkLoad.4.0")
    objBL.ConnectionString = "provider=SQLOLEDB.1;data source=c9laptop;database=msite2;uid=dnndev706conn;pwd=password"
    objBL.ErrorLogFile = "d:\c9webs\msite2\error.log"
    objBL.KeepIdentity = False

    objBL.Execute("myschema.xml", "myfile.xml")
    MsgBox("Completed file import!")
    objBL = Nothing
    'reader.Close()
    strResponse.Close()

End Sub

End Class
```

How can I get the xml from the api call directly into an ADO object that SQLXMLBulkload will accept? Thanks for any help.